# Optimisation problem of two parameters depending on an equation reliant on three parameters

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, matlab

So I'm trying to solve the following optimisation problem either theoretically or in MATLAB but not sure how to approach it. So I have the following function given by 
$$
z(x,y) = \frac{(-x-y-1) + xr + yr^{2} + r^{3}}{(x + 2y + 3)r^2}
$$

and I need to find the lowest value of $z$, essentially optimise the parameters $x$ and $y$, such that roots of the cubic equation given by $ (-x-y-1) + xr + (y - z(x, y))r^{2} + r^{3}$ have absolute value less than $1$. I've tried the `optimproblem` function in MATLAB to help me solve the problem but haven't made any progress.

Comment: What is $r$? Have you looked into fractional optimization?

Comment: r is essentially a value from 0 to 2*pi

Comment: can't you get to $-\infty$ by letting the denominator approach 0 from below?

Comment: yes but then it won't satisfy the second equation which states that the cubic equation must have roots with absolute value less than 1

Comment: your constraints on the roots is equivalent to the roots of the following polynomial:
$$
(r-1)*(2*y+x+2)*(y*r+y+r^2+r+x+1)
$$
beeing less than $(x+2*y+3)$.